# Importing URLs for JSOUP to Scrape via Spreadsheet

Tags: java, excel, web-crawler, jsoup, scrape

I finally got IntelliJ to work. I'm using the code below. It works perfect. I need it to loop over and over and pull links from a spreadsheet to find the price over and over again on different items. I have a spreadsheet with a few sample URLs located in column C starting at row 2. How can I have JSOUP use the URLs in this spreadsheet then output to column D?

```
public class Scraper {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final Document document = Jsoup.connect("examplesite.com").get();

    for (Element row : document.select("#price")) {

        final String price = row.select("#price").text();

        System.out.println(price);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!
Eric

Comment: Seems you have three problems here. 
1. reading xls file,
2. scraping with Jsoup,
3. editing and saving xls file.

Comment: Krystian, thanks for your reply. What do you mean? The program works perfectly right now, it reads what I need from the site I need. I just need it to pull from a sheet then export to a sheet, do you have any ideas? And is XLS preferred over CSV? Thanks again.

Comment: XLS is not preffered over CSV, but it's important to know which one you want to read and edit. CSV can be read as text file line by line, but XLS would require additional library. So is it XLS or CSV? Is column C the last one?

Comment: Krystian,
It can be any format! Right now our sheet is set up as Product ID | Product Name | URL | Price |

The URL is what we are trying to pull from, and Price is where we'd like the extracted data to go.

This video may be similar to what I'm attempting, so it must be possible, but I'm just not at all certain how to get there! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gdi_uekRTeA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JExcel library to read and edit sheets: https://sourceforge.net/projects/jexcelapi/ .

When you download the zip file with library there's also very useful `tutorial.html`.

Explanation in comments:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import jxl.Cell;
import jxl.CellType;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.write.Label;
import jxl.write.WritableSheet;
import jxl.write.WritableWorkbook;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;

public class StackoverflowQuestion51577491 {

    private static final int URL_COLUMN = 2; // Column C
    private static final int PRICE_COLUMN = 3; // Column D

    public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {

        // open worksheet with URLs
        Workbook originalWorkbook = Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("O:/original.xls"));
        // create editable copy
        WritableWorkbook workbook = Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("O:/updated.xls"), originalWorkbook);
        // close read-only workbook as it's not needed anymore
        originalWorkbook.close();
        // get first available sheet
        WritableSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(0);
        // skip title row 0
        int currentRow = 1;
        Cell cell;
        // iterate each cell from column C until we find an empty one
        while (!(cell = sheet.getCell(URL_COLUMN, currentRow)).getType().equals(CellType.EMPTY)) {
            // raed cell contents
            String url = cell.getContents();
            System.out.println("parsing URL: " + url);
            // parse and get the price
            String price = parseUrlWithJsoupAndGetProductPrice(url);
            System.out.println("found price: " + price);
            // create new cell with price
            Label cellWithPrice = new Label(PRICE_COLUMN, currentRow, price);
            sheet.addCell(cellWithPrice);
            // go to next row
            currentRow++;
        }
        // save and close file
        workbook.write();
        workbook.close();
    }

    private static String parseUrlWithJsoupAndGetProductPrice(String url) throws IOException {
        // download page and parse it to Document
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        // get the price from html
        return doc.select("#priceblock_ourprice").text();
    }
}
```

before:
[image]
after:
[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This is extremely helpful and I can tailor it from here to work with my needs. The only other thing I wish to do is possibly look into multithreading? We would have close to 15,000 URLs to parse so I'm not sure if that would be possible. I may have another question about adding product name to the export but will try to figure out myself first. Thank you so much again!