# How to get the JSON data into a string from a .js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, parsing, getjson

I have a js file which contains `createTable(// Create statistics table and // Creates APDEX table)`.

I need to get the `// Create statistics table` values into a string so that I can copy that to an Excel using json2xsl. Is there any way to get those `"Create statistics table"` data values into a string?

I have attached my js file here

```js
function summaryTableHeader(header) {
  var newRow = header.insertRow(-1);
  newRow.className = "tablesorter-no-sort";
  var cell = document.createElement('th');
  cell.setAttribute("data-sorter", false);
  cell.colSpan = 1;
  cell.innerHTML = "Requests";
  newRow.appendChild(cell);

  cell = document.createElement('th');
  cell.setAttribute("data-sorter", false);
  cell.colSpan = 3;
  cell.innerHTML = "Executions";
  newRow.appendChild(cell);

  cell = document.createElement('th');
  cell.setAttribute("data-sorter", false);
  cell.colSpan = 7;
  cell.innerHTML = "Response Times (ms)";
  newRow.appendChild(cell);

  cell = document.createElement('th');
  cell.setAttribute("data-sorter", false);
  cell.colSpan = 2;
  cell.innerHTML = "Network (KB/sec)";
  newRow.appendChild(cell);
}


function createTable(table, info, formatter, defaultSorts, seriesIndex, headerCreator) {
  var tableRef = table[0];

  // Create header and populate it with data.titles array
  var header = tableRef.createTHead();

  // Call callback is available
  if (headerCreator) {
    headerCreator(header);
  }

  var newRow = header.insertRow(-1);
  for (var index = 0; index < info.titles.length; index++) {
    var cell = document.createElement('th');
    cell.innerHTML = info.titles[index];
    newRow.appendChild(cell);
  }

  var tBody;

  // Create overall body if defined
  if (info.overall) {
    tBody = document.createElement('tbody');
    tBody.className = "tablesorter-no-sort";
    tableRef.appendChild(tBody);
    var newRow = tBody.insertRow(-1);
    var data = info.overall.data;
    for (var index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
      var cell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
      cell.innerHTML = formatter ? formatter(index, data[index]) : data[index];
    }
  }

  // Create regular body
  tBody = document.createElement('tbody');
  tableRef.appendChild(tBody);

  var regexp;
  if (seriesFilter) {
    regexp = new RegExp(seriesFilter, 'i');
  }
  // Populate body with data.items array
  for (var index = 0; index < info.items.length; index++) {
    var item = info.items[index];
    if ((!regexp || filtersOnlySampleSeries && !info.supportsControllersDiscrimination || regexp.test(item.data[seriesIndex])) &&
      (!showControllersOnly || !info.supportsControllersDiscrimination || item.isController)) {
      if (item.data.length > 0) {
        var newRow = tBody.insertRow(-1);
        for (var col = 0; col < item.data.length; col++) {
          var cell = newRow.insertCell(-1);
          cell.innerHTML = formatter ? formatter(col, item.data[col]) : item.data[col];
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Add support of columns sort
  table.tablesorter({
    sortList: defaultSorts
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {

  // Customize table sorter default options
  $.extend($.tablesorter.defaults, {
    theme: 'blue',
    cssInfoBlock: "tablesorter-no-sort",
    widthFixed: true,
    widgets: ['zebra']
  });


  // Creates APDEX table
  createTable($("#apdexTable"), {
    "supportsControllersDiscrimination": true,
    "overall": {
      "data": [0.6416666666666667, 500, 1500, "Total"],
      "isController": false
    },
    "titles": ["Apdex", "T (Toleration threshold)", "F (Frustration threshold)", "Label"],
    "items": [{
      "data": [1.0, 500, 1500, "http://10.0.70.18:8443/assets/componentsConf/highcharts.json"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.3, 500, 1500, "Case Search 5 years - HDFC"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [1.0, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Last 7 Days, caseType : All, widgetName : CURRENT_ACTIVITY_ONLINE_ELEMENTS_SUMMARY"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.45, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Last Year, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.5, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Last 90 Days, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [1.0, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Last 30 Days, caseType : Vishing, widgetName : ATTACK_TRENDING_CASES_N_ELEMENTS"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.0, 500, 1500, "Element Search and Export 1 year - All"],
      "isController": true
    }, {
      "data": [0.0, 500, 1500, "Findings Search 1 year - All"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.15, 500, 1500, "Findings Export 2 years - HDFC"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.5, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : YTD, caseType : All, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.3, 500, 1500, "Element Export 2 years - HDFC"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.4, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : YTD, caseType : Vishing, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.0, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Customized 5 Years, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : ATTACK_TRENDING_CASES_N_ELEMENTS"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.5, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : MTD, caseType : All, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.5, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Customized 3 Years, caseType : Brand Abuse, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [1.0, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Last 90 Days, caseType : Vishing, widgetName : ATTACK_TRENDING_CASES_N_ELEMENTS"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.5, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Last Year, caseType : Trojan, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.5, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Customized 2 Years, caseType : Brand Abuse, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [1.0, 500, 1500, "Element Search 3 years - HDFC"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.5, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Last 7 Days, caseType : All, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.55, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Last 30 Days, caseType : Phishing, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.7, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Customized 5 Years, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.4, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Customized 3 Years, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [1.0, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Last Day, caseType : Brand Abuse, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.45, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Customized 2 Years, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.8, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : Last 30 Days, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [1.0, 500, 1500, "Widget Filer -  day : WTD, caseType : Trojan, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN"],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": [0.15, 500, 1500, "Case Search and Export 2 years - HDFC"],
      "isController": true
    }]
  }, function(index, item) {
    switch (index) {
      case 0:
        item = item.toFixed(3);
        break;
      case 1:
      case 2:
        item = formatDuration(item);
        break;
    }
    return item;
  }, [
    [0, 0]
  ], 3);

  // Create statistics table
  createTable($("#statisticsTable"), {
    "supportsControllersDiscrimination": true,
    "overall": {
      "data": ["Total", 3640, 10, 0.27472527472527475, 3639.9299450549524, 13, 538740, 10765.800000000001, 12825.8, 20110.160000000033, 1.7694735670302353, 372.0607477266944, 2.1349031653767496],
      "isController": false
    },
    "titles": ["Label", "#Samples", "KO", "Error %", "Average", "Min", "Max", "90th pct", "95th pct", "99th pct", "Throughput", "Received", "Sent"],
    "items": [{
      "data": ["http://10.0.70.18:8443/assets/componentsConf/highcharts.json", 10, 0, 0.0, 20.4, 13, 27, 27.0, 27.0, 27.0, 126.58227848101266, 152.6651503164557, 46.35581487341772],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Case Search 5 years - HDFC", 10, 0, 0.0, 1255.0, 442, 1665, 1664.3, 1665.0, 1665.0, 1.0187449062754685, 1.0595344972493888, 1.3510308425020374],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Last 7 Days, caseType : All, widgetName : CURRENT_ACTIVITY_ONLINE_ELEMENTS_SUMMARY", 60, 0, 0.0, 38.55, 27, 112, 44.9, 47.949999999999996, 112.0, 5.434782608695652, 3.4816576086956523, 6.644870923913044],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Last Year, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN", 10, 0, 0.0, 1047.6, 471, 1681, 1676.5, 1681.0, 1681.0, 2.1654395842356, 1.057343546990039, 2.6243266836292767],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Last 90 Days, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW", 10, 0, 0.0, 1232.8000000000002, 791, 1472, 1471.5, 1472.0, 1472.0, 6.7658998646820026, 3.4754524695534506, 8.24594046008119],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Last 30 Days, caseType : Vishing, widgetName : ATTACK_TRENDING_CASES_N_ELEMENTS", 10, 0, 0.0, 47.300000000000004, 40, 67, 65.2, 67.0, 67.0, 80.0, 41.40625, 97.5],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Element Search and Export 1 year - All", 10, 0, 0.0, 18169.4, 16511, 22844, 22679.3, 22844.0, 22844.0, 0.4369865408145429, 8869.709134247727, 1.142395478281769],
      "isController": true
    }, {
      "data": ["Findings Search 1 year - All", 10, 0, 0.0, 39922.5, 39823, 40099, 40098.4, 40099.0, 40099.0, 0.24925845609312294, 0.46784643809666243, 0.31838873102520004],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Findings Export 2 years - HDFC", 10, 0, 0.0, 3505.2999999999997, 660, 4744, 4744.0, 4744.0, 4744.0, 0.46268449544255774, 258.4888146023227, 0.5846813838893259],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : YTD, caseType : All, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW", 10, 0, 0.0, 1024.3, 926, 1161, 1158.1, 1161.0, 1161.0, 6.43915003219575, 3.3516278976175147, 7.759678847392145],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Element Export 2 years - HDFC", 10, 0, 0.0, 1637.4, 296, 2263, 2262.9, 2263.0, 2263.0, 0.36537688625817527, 194.47648628466513, 0.4838389235996931],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : YTD, caseType : Vishing, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN", 10, 0, 0.0, 1229.6000000000001, 524, 1585, 1582.4, 1585.0, 1585.0, 3.1938677738741617, 1.559505748961993, 3.839503153944427],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Customized 5 Years, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : ATTACK_TRENDING_CASES_N_ELEMENTS", 10, 0, 0.0, 4181.0, 3998, 4375, 4369.5, 4375.0, 4375.0, 2.2416498542927594, 1.8738791750728534, 2.7539018717776282],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : MTD, caseType : All, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW", 10, 0, 0.0, 802.5999999999999, 729, 887, 883.8, 887.0, 887.0, 8.77963125548727, 4.544145083406497, 10.580141571553995],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Customized 3 Years, caseType : Brand Abuse, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW", 10, 0, 0.0, 845.5, 756, 950, 948.4, 950.0, 950.0, 9.19963201471941, 4.779496320147194, 11.158147424103037],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Last 90 Days, caseType : Vishing, widgetName : ATTACK_TRENDING_CASES_N_ELEMENTS", 10, 0, 0.0, 76.2, 70, 84, 83.5, 84.0, 84.0, 54.6448087431694, 29.136782786885245, 66.59836065573771],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Last Year, caseType : Trojan, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW", 10, 0, 0.0, 603.5999999999999, 517, 687, 685.0, 687.0, 687.0, 11.037527593818986, 5.72356167218543, 13.33341956401766],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Customized 2 Years, caseType : Brand Abuse, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW", 10, 0, 0.0, 774.7, 684, 894, 892.3, 894.0, 894.0, 11.1731843575419, 5.793907122905027, 13.551850558659218],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Element Search 3 years - HDFC", 10, 0, 0.0, 110.6, 90, 149, 147.3, 149.0, 149.0, 0.6148548942449582, 1.9988788505287753, 0.8256108199090015],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Last 7 Days, caseType : All, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW", 10, 0, 0.0, 665.6999999999998, 559, 788, 786.8, 788.0, 788.0, 4.2426813746287655, 2.1959190708527787, 5.112762515910055],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Last 30 Days, caseType : Phishing, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN", 10, 0, 0.0, 1061.5, 387, 1336, 1335.7, 1336.0, 1336.0, 4.249893752656183, 2.3200103591160217, 5.11315342116447],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Customized 5 Years, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN", 10, 0, 0.0, 732.3000000000001, 433, 1052, 1051.0, 1052.0, 1052.0, 2.5329280648429586, 1.2788318452380953, 3.0696911410840935],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Customized 3 Years, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN", 10, 0, 0.0, 1220.1, 670, 1967, 1964.5, 1967.0, 1967.0, 1.9054878048780488, 0.9304139672256098, 2.3092874666539633],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Last Day, caseType : Brand Abuse, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW", 10, 0, 0.0, 340.9, 334, 351, 350.4, 351.0, 351.0, 4.452359750667854, 2.287051981300089, 5.400225400712378],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Customized 2 Years, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN", 10, 0, 0.0, 1037.9, 413, 1528, 1527.3, 1528.0, 1528.0, 2.1593608291945583, 1.0543754048801555, 2.616959754912546],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : Last 30 Days, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : ATTACK_STATUS_OVERVIEW", 10, 0, 0.0, 568.1, 291, 965, 965.0, 965.0, 965.0, 5.040322580645161, 2.5841497605846775, 6.14289314516129],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : WTD, caseType : Trojan, widgetName : SHUTDOWN_MEDIAN", 10, 0, 0.0, 25.7, 23, 29, 28.9, 29.0, 29.0, 4.154549231408392, 2.2355045180722892, 4.990327690070627],
      "isController": false
    }, {
      "data": ["Case Search and Export 2 years - HDFC", 10, 0, 0.0, 2819.0, 505, 5606, 5480.3, 5606.0, 5606.0, 0.2926115581565472, 52.82810213972202, 0.7706771214337967],
      "isController": true
    }, {
      "data": ["Widget Filer -  day : MTD, caseType : Advance Fee Fraud, widgetName : ATTACK_TRENDING_CASES_N_ELEMENTS", 10, 0, 0.0, 37.699999999999996, 30, 43, 42.8, 43.0, 43.0, 37.03703703703704, 18.952546296296294, 45.5005787037037],
      "isController": false
    }]
  }, function(index, item) {
    switch (index) {
      // Errors pct
      case 3:
        item = item.toFixed(2) + '%';
        break;
        // Mean
      case 4:
        // Mean
      case 7:
        // Percentile 1
      case 8:
        // Percentile 2
      case 9:
        // Percentile 3
      case 10:
        // Throughput
      case 11:
        // Kbytes/s
      case 12:
        // Sent Kbytes/s
        item = item.toFixed(2);
        break;
    }
    return item;
  }, [
    [0, 0]
  ], 0, summaryTableHeader);
});
```

Comment: If you have json data and you want to convert it into string then why can't you use "JSON.stringify()" method.

Comment: @Sagar Attached .js file contains many data ,in that i need to get the particular table value (i.e.,// Create statistics table) into a string